# xslt concat variable and string

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm looking for a simpler way to concatenate a variable and a string value. Currently I have the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$var_asset_name">
    <xsl:attribute name="Asset_Name" select="fn:concat(fn:string(.), '_title')"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

with $var_asset_name defined further up. This works, but I'm wondering if there is a simpler way to achieve the same result. I have tried

```
<xsl:attribute name="Asset_Name" select="fn:concat($var_asset_name, '_title')"/>
```

but it did not work (Error: The supplied sequence ('2' item(s)) has the wrong occurrence to match the sequence type xs:anyAtomicType ('zero or one'))

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is wrong for other reasons, not related directly to the question - you are iterating using for-each and and trying to create more than one attribute with the same name. this is just wrong.

Comment: If `$var_asset_name` is a string, `concat($var_asset_name, '_title')` is fine.  The error message and your use of `$var_asset_name` with `xsl:for-each` indicates that `$var_asset_name` is not a string, however.   Please provide a [**Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem, especially including the definition of `$var_asset_name`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

With this input:

```
<root/>
```

The following XSLT(which uses attribute value template):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:variable name="var_asset_name">stack</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="root">
    <root Asset_Name="{$var_asset_name}_overflow"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Would produce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root Asset_Name="stack_overflow"/>
```

I hope you wanted an easier way to create attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. I was actually looking for an easier way to concatenate a variable and a string, without having to use for-each so this doesn't really solve that problem unfortunately

Comment: @ Lech Rzedzicki why is my code "just wrong"? It actually produces the output I need. I was just looking for a way to simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, all XPath versions have a string concatenation function, not a string concatenation operator: [XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-concat), [XPath 2.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-concat), [XPath 3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-concat)